# How do I invoke the shell "file copy dialog" to report the progress of a copy in Win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io, file-copying

How can I copy files by invoking windows "copy files" dialog to do it?

`SHFileOperation` seems like a option, but it is inside our process.

By the way, does `SHFileOperation` have GUI interface? Is it exactly the same as the Windows copy dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is what the [`SHFileOperation` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164.aspx) is designed for. It accepts an [`SHFILEOPSTRUCT` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795.aspx) as its only parameter, which you can use to specify the options that you want.

However, it has been replaced in Windows Vista and later versions with the [`IFileOperation` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775771.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You would pinvoke [`SHFileOperation`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHFileOperation) as in the example here:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class InteropSHFileOperation
    {
        public enum FO_Func : uint
        {
            FO_MOVE = 0x0001,
            FO_COPY = 0x0002,
            FO_DELETE = 0x0003,
            FO_RENAME = 0x0004,
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 2)]
        struct SHFILEOPSTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr hwnd;
            public FO_Func wFunc;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string pFrom;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string pTo;
            public ushort fFlags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public bool fAnyOperationsAborted;
            public IntPtr hNameMappings;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string lpszProgressTitle;

        }

        [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern int SHFileOperation([In, Out] ref SHFILEOPSTRUCT lpFileOp);

        private SHFILEOPSTRUCT _ShFile;
        public FILEOP_FLAGS fFlags;

        public IntPtr hwnd
        {
            set
            {
                this._ShFile.hwnd = value;
            }
        }
        public FO_Func wFunc
        {
            set
            {
                this._ShFile.wFunc = value;
            }
        }

        public string pFrom
        {
            set
            {
                this._ShFile.pFrom = value + '\0' + '\0';
            }
        }
        public string pTo
        {
            set
            {
                this._ShFile.pTo = value + '\0' + '\0';
            }
        }

        public bool fAnyOperationsAborted
        {
            set
            {
                this._ShFile.fAnyOperationsAborted = value;
            }
        }
        public IntPtr hNameMappings
        {
            set
            {
                this._ShFile.hNameMappings = value;
            }
        }
        public string lpszProgressTitle
        {
            set
            {
                this._ShFile.lpszProgressTitle = value + '\0';
            }
        }

        public InteropSHFileOperation()
        {

            this.fFlags = new FILEOP_FLAGS();
            this._ShFile = new SHFILEOPSTRUCT();
            this._ShFile.hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
            this._ShFile.wFunc = FO_Func.FO_COPY;
            this._ShFile.pFrom = "";
            this._ShFile.pTo = "";
            this._ShFile.fAnyOperationsAborted = false;
            this._ShFile.hNameMappings = IntPtr.Zero;
            this._ShFile.lpszProgressTitle = "";

        }

        public bool Execute()
        {
            this._ShFile.fFlags = this.fFlags.Flag;
            return SHFileOperation(ref this._ShFile) == 0;//true if no errors
        }

        public class FILEOP_FLAGS
        {
            [Flags]
            private enum FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM : ushort
            {
                FOF_MULTIDESTFILES = 0x0001,
                FOF_CONFIRMMOUSE = 0x0002,
                FOF_SILENT = 0x0004,  // don't create progress/report
                FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION = 0x0008,
                FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = 0x0010,  // Don't prompt the user.
                FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE = 0x0020,  // Fill in SHFILEOPSTRUCT.hNameMappings
                                                 // Must be freed using SHFreeNameMappings
                FOF_ALLOWUNDO = 0x0040,
                FOF_FILESONLY = 0x0080,  // on *.*, do only files
                FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS = 0x0100,  // means don't show names of files
                FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR = 0x0200,  // don't confirm making any needed dirs
                FOF_NOERRORUI = 0x0400,  // don't put up error UI
                FOF_NOCOPYSECURITYATTRIBS = 0x0800,  // dont copy NT file Security Attributes
                FOF_NORECURSION = 0x1000,  // don't recurse into directories.
                FOF_NO_CONNECTED_ELEMENTS = 0x2000,  // don't operate on connected elements.
                FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING = 0x4000,  // during delete operation, warn if nuking instead of recycling (partially overrides FOF_NOCONFIRMATION)
                FOF_NORECURSEREPARSE = 0x8000,  // treat reparse points as objects, not containers
            }

            public bool FOF_MULTIDESTFILES = false;
            public bool FOF_CONFIRMMOUSE = false;
            public bool FOF_SILENT = false;
            public bool FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION = false;
            public bool FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = false;
            public bool FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE = false;
            public bool FOF_ALLOWUNDO = false;
            public bool FOF_FILESONLY = false;
            public bool FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS = false;
            public bool FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR = false;
            public bool FOF_NOERRORUI = false;
            public bool FOF_NOCOPYSECURITYATTRIBS = false;
            public bool FOF_NORECURSION = false;
            public bool FOF_NO_CONNECTED_ELEMENTS = false;
            public bool FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING = false;
            public bool FOF_NORECURSEREPARSE = false;

            public ushort Flag
            {
                get
                {
                    ushort ReturnValue = 0;

                    if (this.FOF_MULTIDESTFILES)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_MULTIDESTFILES;
                    if (this.FOF_CONFIRMMOUSE)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_CONFIRMMOUSE;
                    if (this.FOF_SILENT)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_SILENT;
                    if (this.FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION;
                    if (this.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
                    if (this.FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE;
                    if (this.FOF_ALLOWUNDO)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_ALLOWUNDO;
                    if (this.FOF_FILESONLY)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_FILESONLY;
                    if (this.FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS;
                    if (this.FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR;
                    if (this.FOF_NOERRORUI)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_NOERRORUI;
                    if (this.FOF_NOCOPYSECURITYATTRIBS)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_NOCOPYSECURITYATTRIBS;
                    if (this.FOF_NORECURSION)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_NORECURSION;
                    if (this.FOF_NO_CONNECTED_ELEMENTS)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_NO_CONNECTED_ELEMENTS;
                    if (this.FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING;
                    if (this.FOF_NORECURSEREPARSE)
                        ReturnValue |= (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_NORECURSEREPARSE;

                    return ReturnValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var fileOp = new InteropSHFileOperation();
            fileOp.pFrom = @"c:\git\WinRTXamlToolkit";
            fileOp.pTo = @"C:\tmp";
            fileOp.wFunc = InteropSHFileOperation.FO_Func.FO_COPY;
            fileOp.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) displays the default shell dialogs for the corresponding file operations, you have a degree of control over this when you call it.